# Echo nested JSON array from related database tables?

Tags: php, json, nested, relational-database

I have two database tables. They are related with `land_contract_annual_price.land_contract_id` -> `land_contract.land_contract_id`.

**Table 'land_contract'**
[image]

**Table 'land_contract_annual_price'**
[image]

When I read from `land_contract`, I want to echo a nested JSON array like this:

```
[  
 {  
  "land_contract_id":118,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_prices":[  
    {"year":1, "price":873.00},
    {"year":2, "price":77289.00},
    {"year":3, "price":8.00},
    {"year":4, "price":0.00},
    {"year":5, "price":8729.00}
  ]
 }
]
```

I'm using prepared statements with PDO to communicate with my database. This is the query I have right now:

```
if (isset($_POST["land_contract_id"])){
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_contract AS lo
                         LEFT JOIN land_contract_annual_price AS loi
                         ON loi.land_contract_id = lo.land_contract_id
                         WHERE lo.land_contract_id = ?");
  $stmt->execute([$land_contract_id]);
} else {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_contract");
  $stmt->execute();
}

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}

if(!$arr) exit('No rows');
echo json_encode($arr);

$stmt = null;
```

That gives me the JSON below, which is not what I want. How can I structure my PHP to get the JSON array above?

```
[
 {
  "land_contract_id":127,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_price_id":1,
  "land_contract_annual_price_year":1,
  "land_contract_annual_price_amount":"873.00"
},
{
  "land_contract_id":127,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_price_id":2,
  "land_contract_annual_price_year":2,
  "land_contract_annual_price_amount":"77289.00"
},
{
  "land_contract_id":127,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_price_id":3,
  "land_contract_annual_price_year":3,
  "land_contract_annual_price_amount":"8.00"
},
{
  "land_contract_id":127,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_price_id":4,
  "land_contract_annual_price_year":4,
  "land_contract_annual_price_amount":"0.00"
},
{
  "land_contract_id":127,
  "land_contract_name":"Avtalsnamn",
  "location_id":71,
  "land_contract_link":"",
  "land_contract_notes":"",
  "land_owner_id":2,
  "land_contract_start_date":"2019-07-25",
  "land_contract_end_date":"2023-07-25",
  "land_contract_terminated":"false",
  "land_contract_payment_interval":"Halv\u00e5rsvis",
  "land_contract_price_type":"R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris",
  "land_contract_fixed_annual_price":null,
  "land_contract_annual_price_id":5,
  "land_contract_annual_price_year":5,
  "land_contract_annual_price_amount":"8729.00"
 }
]
```

Logic for @potiev:

```
if (isset($_POST["land_contract_id"]) {

  // Get data from land_contract where land_contract_id is $land_contract_id. Store as $landContract.

  if (land_contract_price_type == 'Rörligt årspris') {

    // Get additional data from land_contract_annual_price where land_contract_id is $land_contract_id
    // Attach land_contract_annual_prices to $landContract
    // Echo $landContract as JSON

  } else if (land_contract_price_type == 'Fast årspris') {

    // Echo $landContract as JSON

  }
} else {

  // Get all land contracts in land_contract

  For every land contract() {

    if (land_contract_price_type == 'Rörligt årspris') {

      // Get additional data from land_contract_annual_price
      // Attach land_contract_annual_prices to land contract

    } 

    Echo all land contracts as JSON

  }


}
```

Comment: u need to re structure this area `$arr[] = $row;`

Comment: @devpro Ok. In what way?

Comment: i suggest you get the result without LEFT JOIN otherwise its difficult to fetch other table columns

Comment: @devpro What should I use instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: i think u can use your second query in while loop

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your query in two parts.

```
if (isset($_POST["land_contract_id"])){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_contract WHERE land_contract_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$land_contract_id]);
    $landContract = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (isset($landContract)) {

        if ($landContract['land_contract_price_type'] == 'Rörligt årspris') {
            $landContract['land_contract_annual_prices'] = [];
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT land_contract_annual_price_year as year, land_contract_annual_price_amount as price FROM land_contract_annual_price WHERE land_contract_id = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$land_contract_id]);
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $landContract['land_contract_annual_prices'][] = $row;
            }
        }

        $arr[] = $landContract;
    }
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_contract");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}


if(!$arr) exit('No rows');
echo json_encode($arr);

$stmt = null;
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to say that I don't know if a given land_contract has any rows in land_contract_annual_prices. The way to check that is if land_contract_price_type has the value of "Rörligt årspris" (I don't know why it turns up as "R\u00f6rligt \u00e5rspris" in my example).

Comment: use html entity decode for this issue @RawlandHustle

Comment: I added checking `land_contract_price_type` before selecting prices from database

Comment: Thanks, it's almos there! Look at the array `land_contract_annual_prices` in the reference JSON file in my question. I don't want to get  land_contract_annual_price_id or land_contract_id from land_contract_annual_price . Also, land_contract_annual_price_year should be presented as a property name, like "year 1", and land_contract_annual_price_amount should be the property value.

Comment: Or, land_contract_annual_price_year and land_contract_annual_price_amount  can be divided like this, it does not matter: `{"year":1, "price":873.00}`. That's actually better!

Comment: I have updated the reference JSON in my question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: If my answer helps you, please select it as true answer

Comment: I removed your extra 'm' in 'ammount' and now your code works perfectly! Thank you very much for your time and help! I have accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Actually, I think your code might be missing some logic. What if `$_POST["land_contract_id"]` is set but `$landContract['land_contract_price_type']` is something else than "Rörligt årspris"? What *should* happen in that case is that this query should be run: `"SELECT * FROM land_contract"`.

Comment: Also, if `$_POST["land_contract_id"]` **is** set, but `$landContract['land_contract_price_type']` is "Rörligt pris", this query should be run: `"SELECT land_contract_annual_price_year as year, land_contract_annual_price_amount as price FROM land_contract_annual_price WHERE land_contract_id = ?"`.

Comment: Why if $_POST["land_contract_id"] is set, why you want to show all land contracts? You said: **I'm so sorry, I forgot to say that I don't know if a given land_contract has any rows in land_contract_annual_prices. The way to check that is if land_contract_price_type has the value of "Rörligt årspris"** - so that, why you want run `SELECT land_contract_annual_price_year as year, land_contract_annual_price_amount as price FROM land_contract_annual_price WHERE land_contract_id = ?`?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled. I have updated my original question for you. I have written the logic in text since I don't know how to write it in code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197003/discussion-between-rawland-hustle-and-potiev).